OpenBSD httpd location match patterns rule returns 404 for anything beginning with any character in the set
In configuring location match rules for OpenBSD httpd, which uses patterns, an OpenBSD implementation of Lua patterns, the following rules result in any request that begins with one of the characters (l,i,orb) to be URL 404 due to not being processed by the second rule. (This is to support rewrites for DokuWiki URL Rewriting).
The following two rules are part of the configuration that I suspect are the problem:
        location match "/(lib/.*)" {
                request rewrite "/%1"
        }

        location match "/([^lib])" {
                request rewrite "/doku.php?id=$DOCUMENT_URI&$QUERY_STRING"
        }

(Note thatL, I, or B produce the desired output.)
I have tried changing the sets, but I am just guessing and I think that the concept I am missing is to understand how to make a rule where only lib is interpreted for the first rule (I think this is already correct) and everything not lib is interpreted for the second rule (which I think is the problem rule since the problem persists even when the first rule is commented).

You want to match anything but anything starting with lib there?

The first rule should match anything starting with lib/ and the second rule should match anything is not lib - if that makes sense?

OK, if it only supports Lua patterns, then there is no solution for this.

The other rule for locations (location) uses shell globbing. Since httpd evaluates rules sequentially and uses the first matching rule, I think another option is to create a rule for each character l, i, b.

The solution is to use a completely different second rule:
    location "/*" {
        request rewrite "/doku.php?id=$DOCUMENT_URI&$QUERY_STRING"
    }

Since httpd evaluates rules sequentially and uses the first matching rule, the match for everything that is not lib/ will pass the first rule, so it doesn't need to be considered when creating the second rule.
